# Microsoft Bot Framework: LuisRecognizer Error While Trying to Connect nodeJS with Luis Using Bot Emulator; Cannot Receive Desired Message

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to connect to my Luis app using Bot Emulator.

I have an intent named "Greet" in the Luis app, and am testing it in the Bot Emulator.

The Bot Emulator keeps replying `Oops there is something went wrong.`, after I typed in my training phrase.

For example, "Hi", in the "Greet" intent.

Please tell me what I did was wrong. Thank you very much!

The following pictures are the screenshot of Bot Emulator and the terminal returning an error message.

**Bot Emulator showing "Oops, something went wrong and we need to start again after I said "Hello.":**

[image: Bot Emulator showing "Oops, something went wrong and we need to start again after I said "Hello."]

**Cache gave an error message at `request._callback` and `self._callback`:**

[image: Cache gave an error message at request._callback and self._callback]

The following is my NodeJS code (I had my LuisAPIKey and LuisAppId in my code locally, here I deleted them):

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var server = restify.createServer();

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3987, function () {
     console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector();

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

var luisAppId = '';
var luisAPIKey = '';
var luisAPIHostName = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';

const luisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;

var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(luisModelUrl);
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({
    recognizers: [recognizer]
})

bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('Greet', (session) =>{
    session.send("Hello there! How can I help you today?");
})
.onDefault((session, args, next) => {
    console.log(args);
    session.send("Sorry, I did not understand.");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your error message is not complete outputed, i reproduce your issue, and the error message shoule be:

```
Error: { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
UniversalBot.js:548
    at Request._callback (c:\WorkSpace\bot framework\nodejs test\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\dialogs\LuisRecognizer.js:101:31)
    at Request.self.callback (c:\WorkSpace\bot framework\nodejs test\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Request.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (c:\WorkSpace\bot framework\nodejs test\node_modules\request\request.js:1157:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Request.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\WorkSpace\bot framework\nodejs test\node_modules\request\request.js:1079:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
/ - ERROR: { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

So the root case, it that you concoct the LUIS URL in incorrect format. you missed `\` after `/luis/v2.0/apps`,
please modify to:

```
const luisModelUrl = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey;
```